# How Do I use a bunch of DAO's using in-memory derby database using spring autowiring.?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, testing, in-memory-database

I have a collection of DALS such as Transaction DAO, Billing DAO etc. Each of them have CRUD operations and I need to use that methods in my project using spring autowiring. In some of the projects that I have checked out, I saw that they are fetching the data inmemory by querying. However, I have to use the DAL's that have already been written and have all the CRUD operations.

For example:

```
        @Autowired
        TransactionDAO transactionDAO

        @Autowired
        BillingDAO billingDAO

   @Test
   public void testImplementSearchMethodForDAO() throws Exception{

   TransactionVO transactionVO = getTransVO();
   BillingVO billingVO = getBillingVO();
   List<TransactionVO> VOList1 = transactionDAO.searchList(transactionVO);
   List<BillingVO> VOList2 = billingDAO.searchList(billingVO);
   assertThat(VOList1.size()).isEqualto(1));
   assertThat(VOList1.size()).isEqualto(1));
   }
  (Assuming I added one VO value in each table).

 If you need any more clarifications, I will be glad to provide you.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setters and use the @Autowire annotation on the setters. Your test code must inject the DAOs using these setters. In you tests you build in mem: db instance and build a connection pool or datasource or whatever you need and then build the DAOs based of that.

Your setup() would something like this

```
BoneCPConfig config = new BoneCPConfig();
config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test_common;shutDown=false");
config.setUsername("sa");
config.setPassword("");
JdbcTemplate dataSource = new BoneCPDataSource(config);
jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
//If you are using named queries
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
//create necessary tables etc here.
setupDb(jdbcTemplate);

SomeBean anotherBean = new SomeBean();

YourDAO dao = new YourDAOImpl();
dao.setNamedJdbcTemplate(namedParameterJdbcTemplate);
dao.setSomeOtherBean(anotherBean);

//Mimic spring container if you implement InitialzingBean

dao.afterPropertiesSet();
```

Once all the dependencies are injected you run your tests as usual.

Comment: Can you provide a dummy example ?

Comment: The point is you can test your DAOs without worrying about spring. I'll type up something soon.